# Open chrome tab from terminal in specific window

Tags: command-line, bash, multiple-monitors, google-chrome

Most of the time, I will have two chrome windows open, one on each screen. I wrote a script that automatically opens a new chrome tab whenever I submit a "job", this takes me to the job logs. However, it always opens this tab on my main monitor (the one I am also coding on), but I would like it to open this tab in the chrome window on my secondary monitor (laptop screen in this case). Is there a way to choose where to open this new tab?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in Windows Terminal.